# Getting Avatar from Twitter user_timeline api 1.1

Tags: php, wordpress, api, twitter

I have got everything to work apart from the avatar is not showing.

For the life of me I cant find out why :(

Here is my snippet which retrieves the code:

```
$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($instance['consumerkey'], $instance['consumersecret'], $instance['accesstoken'], $instance['accesstokensecret']);
                        $tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$instance['username']."&count=10") or die('Couldn\'t retrieve tweets! Wrong username?');


                        if(!empty($tweets->errors)){
                            if($tweets->errors[0]->message == 'Invalid or expired token'){
                                echo '<strong>'.$tweets->errors[0]->message.'!</strong><br />You\'ll need to regenerate it <a href="https://dev.twitter.com/apps" target="_blank">here</a>!' . $after_widget;
                            }else{
                                echo '<strong>'.$tweets->errors[0]->message.'</strong>' . $after_widget;
                            }
                            return;
                        }

                        for($i = 0;$i <= count($tweets); $i++){
                            if(!empty($tweets[$i])){
                                $tweets_array[$i]['created_at'] = $tweets[$i]->created_at;
                                $tweets_array[$i]['text'] = $tweets[$i]->text;          
                                $tweets_array[$i]['status_id'] = $tweets[$i]->id_str;
                                $tweets_array[$i]['profile_image_url'] = $tweets[$i]->profile_image_url;        
                            }
                        }
```

This is in-fact a snippet from a wordpress plugin which i am trying to customise with relative success apart from I cant seem to get the avatar to be retrieved :(

Could a twitter api guru shout out where im going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason was because I was using:

```
$tweets_array[$i]['profile_image_url'] = $tweets[$i]->profile_image_url;
```

Instead of calling an object and then ad array like:

```
$tweets_array[$i]['profile_image_url'] = $tweets[$i]->use->profile_image_url;
```